# No context hint and false "unresolved reference" on discord.Interaction.response.send_message in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py, ide

I'm using PyCharm to write a Discord bot with discord.py. Every time I use *send_message* method from the *InteractionResponse* class, I get this IDE warning: `Cannot find reference "send_message" in '() -> InteractionResponse'`. There is also no context hint for that particular method when typing `interaction.response.`

However, the code is working fine and I can see that there is a *send_message* method in the *InteractionResponse* class if I just ctrl+click into it. I would love to get rid of the IDE warning, as it's distracting. Getting a context hint would be nice too, as the method is frequently used. Ideally I would love to be able to "tell" IDE that there is this method in this class. Any ideas?

This is the example code that will cause the issue:

```py
import discord

async def respond_to_message(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello world")
```

I have also tried the "File -> Repair IDE" option all the way down, Invalidate Caches included, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions to remove the IDE warning.

1. Turning off `Unresolved References` inspection checking in the setting. Go to `settings -> Editor -> Inspections`, under `Python`, there is a yellow warning called `Unsolved References`, uncheck the option and click apply. Pros: simple with one click. Cons: It will not show any unresolved references warning later for your other code files.
2. Adding comment to avoid inspection check for specific parts of code. The multiple lines version is that (the following example will turn off unresolved references check for `YourClass()`

```py
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class YourClass(...):
  # Your code
```

3. Adding comment to suppress single line inspection

```py
await interaction.response.send_message(...)  # noqa
```

Comment: These are okay options if nothing else work, but is there no way to tell IDE that there is this method in this class?

Comment: @MeloMan There is another way to specifically ignore `edit_message` and `send_message` in your pycharm inspection. Go to `settings -> editor -> python -> Unresolved References`, there is an ignored options, you can insert these two strings in the options to let them get ignored. The bad side of this is it will ignore all "edit_message" and "send_message" methods in all of your python files. I don't think there are other ways to get around this.