# Discord.py's interaction.response has no send_message method

Tags: python, discord.py

I was transitioning my old discord bot from 1.7.3 (before slash commands) to 2.3 and encountered an error when trying to send a message upon the use of a command. I have seen tutorials and they all use interaction.response.send_message() to send a message back in the channel where the command was taken.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import cmath
import datetime
import json
import os
import pickle
import youtube_dl
import discord
import wolframalpha
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from discord.utils import get
import requests
import pickle
import asyncio
import chatbot
print(discord.__version__)
client = wolframalpha.Client(OTHER_TOKEN)
yaml = YAML()

with open("./config.yml", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    config = yaml.load(file)


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = config['Prefix'], intents=discord.Intents.all())

log_channel_id = config['Log Channel ID']

bot.embed_color = discord.Color.from_rgb(
    config['Embed Settings']['Colors']['r'],
    config['Embed Settings']['Colors']['g'],
    config['Embed Settings']['Colors']['b']
)
bot.footer = config['Embed Settings']['Footer']['Text']
bot.footer_image = config['Embed Settings']['Footer']['Icon URL']
bot.prefix = config['Prefix']
bot.playing_status = config['Playing Status'].format(prefix = bot.prefix)

bot.TOKEN = os.getenv(config['Bot Token Variable Name'])

bot.members = []
bot.owner = [500033041545166864]
extensions = sorted([
    'Cogs.general'
])

for extension in extensions:
    bot.load_extension(extension)

bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} and connected to discord! (ID: {bot.user.id})")

    game = discord.Game(name = bot.playing_status)
    await bot.change_presence(activity = game)
    await bot.tree.sync()
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"{bot.user.name} is online!",
        color = bot.embed_color,
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
    )
    embed.set_footer(
        text = bot.footer,
        icon_url = bot.footer_image
    )

    bot.log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await bot.log_channel.send(embed = embed)

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.start(TOKEN, reconnect=True)

@bot.tree.command(name="whois", description="Shows information about a member or yourself if left blank")
async def userinfo(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = interaction.user if not member else member
    print(member.color)
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.color, timestamp=interaction.created_at)

    embed.set_author(name=f"User Info - {member}")
    print(member.avatar.url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
    print(member.display_name)
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=str(member.display_name), inline = True)
    print(member.top_role.mention)
    embed.add_field(name="Top role", value=member.top_role.mention, inline = True)
    print(member.bot)
    embed.add_field(name="Bot?", value=member.bot, inline = True)
    print("HI")
    embed.set_author(
        name=interaction.user.name,
        icon_url=interaction.user.avatar.url
    )
    embed.set_footer(
        text="Requested by " + interaction.user.name,
        icon_url= bot.footer_image
    )
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    await interaction.message.add_reaction('✅')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is the current output (there are a few warning but I believe they are not related to the issue at hand):

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Cloud\Programming\Python\Anaconda\envs\3.9_bot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\compat\v2_compat.py:107: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
curses is not supported on this machine (please install/reinstall curses for an optimal experience)
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Cloud\Programming\Python\Anaconda\envs\3.9_bot\lib\site-packages\tflearn\initializations.py:164: calling TruncatedNormal.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
C:\Cloud\Programming\Python\CodingProjects\Bot Code\main.py:48: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(extension)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2.3.2
Logged in as Wolf Extension#0723 and connected to discord! (ID: 741545843986923580)
```

For some reason, in my code, interact.response has no send_message() method. It just displays "Cannot find reference 'send_message' in '() -> InteractionResponse'" when I hover over the method in pycharm. I get no errors in my terminal though which may be due to all of the async activity that I don't fully understand. On the discord side, I just get "The application did not respond". Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fix the warning by adding await to `await bot.load_extension(extension)`

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited

2. The PyCharm error is [a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577197/no-context-hint-and-false-unresolved-reference-on-discord-interaction-response): the typing seems incomplete. At runtime, though, that method does exist.

You should do some more debugging to figure out where it's actually failing, and whether any connectivity works.

Comment: Thank you, that is some new information to me. Fixing the RuntimeWarning seems to have fixed the issue.