# Discord.py app_commands send_message not being recognised

Tags: python, discord.py

When making app commands i always see peaople do

```
@app_commands.command()
async def first_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Text", ephemeral=True)
```

But when i do that send_message isnt recognised
it only works when i do

```
@app_commands.command()
async def first_command(interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Text", ephemeral=True)
```

And i'm wondering if there are any consequences to not using the interactio: discord interaction and using just interaction instead and what the cause to this problem might be. this is the message i get Cannot find reference 'send_message' in '() -> InteractionResponse'

I am new to this whole thing, especially the discord.py library so i dont really know what to try or where to even beggin

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using PyCharm IDE. This IDE does not understand the typing of the `discord.py` library very well and indicates that the method does not exist. You don't need to worry about this, just ignore Pycharm's warning. Don't stop specifying the type of your variable because of this bug. Keep using `interaction: discord.Interaction`. I recommend that you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577197/no-context-hint-and-false-unresolved-reference-on-discord-interaction-response) about how to ignore these alerts.